# Java 8 filtering a string

Tags: java, string, java-8

I have a method to remove some characters from a string. Is there a better way to do this using java 8?

```
public String filter(String test) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        if (MYCOLLECTION.contains(test.charAt(i))) {
            builder .append(test.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return builder .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
Set<Character> filter = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a','b','c'));
String filtered = "abcdefga".chars ()
                            .filter(i -> filter.contains((char) i))
                            .mapToObj(i -> "" + (char) i)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println (filtered);
```

Output:

```
abca
```

Note: `filter` serves the same purpose as your `MYCOLLECTION` - I just gave it a more meaningful name and used a `Set` for better performance of `contains`.

It could have been cleaner if there was a `CharStream` (i.e. stream of primitive `char`s), so I wouldn't have to use an `IntStream`.

Comment: You can use `.mapToObj(Character::toString)` over `.mapToObj(i -> "" + (char) i)`, right?

Comment: @Michael It would have to be `.mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char) i))`. The suggested method reference doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: Don't know what you're trying, works for me https://ideone.com/GpgXpG

Comment: @Michael I'm getting `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <U> mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U>)` with your code on Eclipse. Java 8.

Comment: @Michael your variant works on ideone, because [`Character.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) has been added in Java 11.

Comment: This stream variant doesn’t look like an improvement over the original loop code to me. And it surely doesn’t add to performance.

Comment: @Holger I was wondering about something simpler like `test.replaceAll("^[^"+ __ + "]+$","")` to work here to reduce the complexity. But the "__" construction might just be complicated?

Comment: @Naman like `filtered = inputString.replaceAll( filter.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("", "[^", "]")),"")`? It only works when the characters have no special meaning (or you’d need additional efforts). Unless the filter characters are constant, nothing can beat the simple loop solution…

Answer (score 1):

"Better" by what metric? Here's how I would write it

```
final String filtered = test.chars()
    .mapToObj(chr -> (char) chr)    // IntStream -> Stream<Character>
    .filter(MYCOLLECTION::contains)
    .collect(
        Collector.of(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::toString)
    );
```

The collector is a bit ugly, I would probably extract it to its own method

```
private static Collector<Character, StringBuilder, String> characterCollector()
{
    return Collector.of(
        StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::append,
        StringBuilder::append,
        StringBuilder::toString
    );
}
```

Then call this instead

```
.collect(characterCollector())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library, the following will work using Java 8 with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
CharSet set = CharSets.immutable.with('a', 'b', 'c');
CharAdapter chars = Strings.asChars("a1b2c3");
String string = chars.select(set::contains).toString();
Assert.assertEquals("abc", string);
```

Eclipse Collections has support for primitive collections so there is no need to box `char` values as `Character` instances.

You can also exclude instead of include characters using the method named `reject` which is the opposite of `select`.

```
CharSet set = CharSets.immutable.with('a', 'b', 'c');
CharAdapter chars = Strings.asChars("a1b2c3");
String include = chars.select(set::contains).toString();
String exclude = chars.reject(set::contains).toString();
Assert.assertEquals("abc", include);
Assert.assertEquals("123", exclude);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way using Regex

```
var string = "what ever you want!";

final var charSet = "".,;:!@";

final var stringResult = string.replaceAll("[" + charSet + "]", "");

>> ""what ever you want"
```